# About constructors, super and inheritance

Tags: java

Super is non static variable, so it should be used with some object reference.
But here below, the object is not yet created, so on which object super is called ?

```
class A{}
class B extends A{
B() { super(); }
```

If object of B is created in main method.

Comment: Constructors have a very specific signature to follow `[visibility] ClassName([Parameters ...])`. Why would you wont to made it static ?

Comment: I am unsure what you wanna achieve but static blocks are made to address your requirement. `static { //any code that you need to invoke while class loading, before even any constructors are called }`

Comment: I suggest you look at this answer first. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3903551/762395

Comment: class A{} class B extends A{} , now if i create object of B in main , on what object constructor of A is called ?

Comment: Ok, you have problems to understand inheritance with the constructor... the constructor of A will be "called" in the instance of B you have created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [order of constructor calls in multilevel inheritance in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806342/order-of-constructor-calls-in-multilevel-inheritance-in-java) or [this bad answer but with lots of duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899863/java-why-does-my-class-automatically-inherits-constructor-from-superclass?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are not static. This is obvious, since you can use `this` in the constructor. The object it works on is already allocated, it is just not completely initialized.

Comment: I don't like the example since `this` is not limited to the constructor but visible from every non-static methods. You are just saying that constructors are not static ;)

Comment: i'm not good at explaining, this is what i was asking,                                class A{}
class B extends A{} , now if i create object of B in main , on what object constructor of A is called ?