# why superclass gets executed first in this program - although I have no main method?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, super

When I run the following code:

```
public class Employee extends Person
{ 
   public Employee()
   {
       this("Employee call 1");
       System.out.println("Employee call 2");
   }
   public Employee(String s)
   {
    System.out.println(s); 
   }
}

public class Person
{
   public Person()
   {
     System.out.println("Person call");
   }
}

public class Faculty extends Employee
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
    new Faculty();
  }
  public Faculty()
  {
    System.out.println("Faculty call");
  }
}
```

I get the following output:

Person call

Employee call 1

Employee call 2

Faculty call

I wanna know why it prints the superclass content then next subclass then next subclass although I have main method in the Faculty subclass. Can you tell me how is it traced?

Thank you.

Comment: You should do some research on inheritance concepts

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508202/11434552), there is an implicit call to `super` for every class in `Java` at the start of the constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Why does my class automatically inherits constructor from superclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899863/java-why-does-my-class-automatically-inherits-constructor-from-superclass)

Comment: this inheritance topic name is  "chain of inheritance" you can search about it on google for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with inheritance it's always the parent's classes constructors that get executed, regardless if your instance is for the child.

Comment: The constructors of *every* class in the hierarchy between `Object` and the class itself are executed, starting with `Object`.